How to solve the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x} \sin x}{(e^{3 x} + 1) x^{3/10}} dx$
$$
\mbox{How to solve the following integral ?}:\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\rm e}^{-x}\sin\left(x\right)}{\left({\rm e}^{3 x} + 1\right)x^{3/10}}{\rm d}x
$$

I think it cannot be solved using elementary functions.
Solution may obtained through series or special functions ?.
$\tt Wolfram\ Alpha$ gives approximate value as $0.0605704$.


Maple says
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-x\right)\cdot \sin\left(x\right)}{\left(\exp\left(3x\right)+1\right)\cdot x^{\frac{3}{10}}} dx=\frac{i}{6} \Gamma ! \left(\frac{7}{10}\right) \left(\frac{3}{\left(1+i\right)^{\frac{7}{10}}}-\Phi! \left(-1,\frac{7}{10},\frac{1}{3}+\frac{i}{3}\right) 3^{\frac{3}{10}}-\frac{3}{\left(1-i\right)^{\frac{7}{10}}}+\Phi! \left(-1,\frac{7}{10},\frac{1}{3}-\frac{i}{3}\right) 3^{\frac{3}{10}}\right)$$
with $\Phi(z,a,v)$ the Lerch Phi function.

My Maple 17 does not produce this output. Is there any special way to put this in Maple?

See Maple worksheet MSE_Q4927910

$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x} \sin x}{(e^{3 x} + 1) x^{3/10}} dx\\
&=&\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(1-i)x}}{(e^{3 x} + 1) x^{3/10}} dx=\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-(4-i)x}}{(1+e^{-3 x}) x^{3/10}} \\
&=&\Im\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-(4-i)x}}{x^{3/10}}(-1)^ne^{-3nx} dx \\
&=&\Im\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{-3/10}e^{-(3n+4-i)x} dx \\
&=&\Im\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(\frac7{10})}{(3n+4-i)^{\frac7{10}}}\\
&=&\Im\frac{\Gamma(\frac7{10})}{6^{7/10}} \bigg[\zeta \left(\frac{7}{10},\frac{2}{3}-\frac{i}{6}\right)-\zeta
   \left(\frac{7}{10},\frac{7}{6}-\frac{i}{6}\right)\bigg]
\end{eqnarray}$$

and what would be the imaginary part of the final expression ?

There is no explicit expression of imaginary part for Riemann Zeta function.

A good series approximation can obtained via series $$ \sin{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},\quad \frac{1}{1+x} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^mx^m,\, |x|<1. $$
The integral can be simplified as $$\begin{align*} \int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x} \sin x}{(e^{3 x} + 1) x^{3/10}} dx &= \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x^{3/10}} \right) \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-3x}} \right)e^{-4x} dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^{\infty}x^{2n+\frac{7}{10}}e^{-(3m+4)x}dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{(2n+1)!} \frac{\Gamma\left(2n+\frac{17}{10}\right)}{(3m+4)^{2n+\frac{17}{10}}}.\end{align*}$$
This sum converges extremely fast. An approximation gives $0.0605703755599221$.
